# Shannon Information weighted by probability of different types

Tags: information-theory

Suppose I have n independent types in a system, each existing with probability t_i i=1,..,n (so the sum of t_i's=1). Suppose also that I can calculate the Shannon Entropy for each type, call this value S_i.

1) Does it make sense to then calculate a weighted sum such as H= -sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i * S_i?

2) How could I compare H values of two systems with different number of types? (e.g., system 1 has n=2 types and system 2 has n=4 types).

Comment: The answer to (1) is yes. If your "types" are truly independent, then the information is additive. Otherwise, you need to compute the information encoded in the joint probability distribution. The answer to (2) very much depends on the question you would like to answer. Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For (2), both system 1 and system 2 have some H value (H1 and H2), and I guess my underlying question is whether H1>H2 implies system 1 is more complex than H2, or whether I need to do something else such as scaling or maybe ">" is the wrong operation? What is the relationship between the number of types and H? Not 100% sure that is clear enough...

Comment: Entropy at it's core is a measure of dispersion (e.g. for continuous, unimodal distributions, it is very tightly linked to the variance of the distribution). If you have 2 systems and one has more possible states (i.e. combinations of different values of your "types", more commonly referred to as state variables or dimensions) and these states are actually observed,  then the system with more states will have a higher entropy / will be more complex.

Comment: However, that is generally not very surprising. Entropy is typically measured in bits (the same bits as in 8 bits = 1 byte). Your question is hence basically asking whether you can say that one can store more information in an array of size 4 versus an array of size 2.

Comment: To solidify my understanding of your reply: what if each "type" has the same number of potential states, but their probability of being in any of those states differs? For example, say you have a 20% chance of being type 1, and 80% chance of being type 2, and within each of those types there are a constant X potential states. Then, do the following makes sense: (a) In both cases you have the same set of potential states, but a different probability distribution over those states. Weighting the calculation of H by the probability of being that "type" is OK if the types are independent.

Comment: (b) A system with 2 "types" vs one with 3 "types" should have a higher entropy when the same X states in each type have non-zero probability. It's the number of non-zero state probabilities that seems to be the major driver of the resulting H value, not necessarily the number of potential "types", right?

Comment: I don't fully understand the scenario in a). Maybe you could amend your question with an actual description of the setup. For example: here is system A; system A has three state variables; variable A1 assumes state "0" with probability 0.23 and state "1" with probability 0.77; variable A2 assumes state .... There is another system B with state variables B1, B2, ..., B6. etc.

Comment: Regarding b): Variables that are with probability p=1 in a given state are not actually variables and hence do not contribute to the entropy of the system (they have no variance). Variable states that are never visited also do not contribute to the entropy of the system (which makes sense if you think of entropy as a measure of dispersion).

Comment: OK, let me try...So, system A and B both having the same set of potential states X1, ..., Xn. In A we have two "types", A1 and A2, each having some probability for each of X1,...,Xn as well as a probability of observing each type, e.g., A1=0.25 and A2=0.75. System B as 3 "types" B1, B2 and B3, each having some probability for each of X1,...,Xn and a probability of observing each "type", say B1=0.1, B2=0.4, B3=0.5. So, while the state variables are the same in both A and B, they are completely different systems.